# How can I make the value of a user's input into a variable with a usable value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import*

branch_width=4
grass_color=input("Would you like your grass to be snowy, dead, or healthy? ")
sky_color=input("Would you like it to be morning, afternoon, or evening? ")

morning="cadetblue"
afternoon="cornflowerblue"
evening="royalblue"
snowy="snow"
dead="wheat"
healthy="darkgreen"
```

Every time I try to use the input as `color(sky_color)`, the user's input is not translated to `morning="cadetblue"`, etc, which returns an error. How do I fix this? Do I need to just make the user type in the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused variable names and character strings.
You set a variable called *morning* to a string "cadetblue".
This has nothing to do with an input string "morning". **You** have to set that up explicitly.

A dictionary would help here:

```
interpret_color = {
    "morning": "cadetblue",
    "afternoon": "cornflowerblue",
    "evening": "royalblue",
    "snowy": "snow",
    "dead": "wheat",
    "healthy": "darkgreen"
}
```

Now you can try

```
color(interpret_color(sky_color))
```

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Syntax error: Square brackets for your dictionary access for interpret_color.

Comment: @ldjaw, I don't know what you're seeing, but I'm seeing the proper braces.  The dangling comma (now gone) wouldn't have helped, though.

Comment: You have: `color(interpret_color(sky_color))`. Your dictionary should be accessed as `color(interpret_color[sky_color])`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Programming in general, and Python in particular, have some really neat features, once you learn to think in terms of algorithm flow and data flow.